# registration django 0.8

Tags: python, django, web

use django registration 0.8 alpha from Bennet!
When I click on the activation link the user switches from inactive to active!  But the the website says a different thing.

{% if account %}
Thanks  activation complete! You may now using the username and password you set at registration.
{% else %}
Oops it seems that your activation key is invalid. Please check the url again.
{% endif %}

How can I force the {{ account }}!

THANKS SO MUCH FOR THE RIGHT ANSWER! I am disparing! Can't find a solution!

Craphunter

Answer (score 0):

On my site there isn't just one activation page.  "activate.html" is used when activation fails and "activation_complete.html" is used when activation works.

[Quickstart Documentation](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/docs/quickstart.rst) mirrors this.